# ToConstant while binding in Kernel

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject.web

We have a code something like below.

```
var xyz = method(); //method() returns an interface say **Interface1**

kernel.Bind<**Interface1**>().ToConstant(xyz);
```

I saw on stackoverflow at the below link:

[Usage of binding to constants and binding to types in scopes with Ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682042/usage-of-binding-to-constants-and-binding-to-types-in-scopes-with-ninject)

Can we use `Kernel.Bind<**Interface1**>().To(typeof(xyz)).InSingletonScope()` if we want the object creation not at the this point but when call is made.

Comment: Use [ToMethod](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context#factory-methods).

Answer (score 2):

```
Bind<Interface1>().ToMethod(context => method()).InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: Thanks. so the difference between kernel.Bind<**Interface1**>().ToConstant(xyz); and the one you gave above is the time when object is created or something else as well

Comment: @Vicky: Correct.

Comment: one more question. what will happen if I remove InSingletonScope() and just keep Bind<Interface1>().ToMethod(context => method()) ?

Comment: In that case `method()` will be called over and over again, instead of just once.