# Is this the right way to use Ninject Dependency Injection to bind HttpClient?

Tags: c#

Is this the right way to use Ninject Dependency Injection to bind HttpClient?

```
Bind<HttpClient>().To<HttpClient>().InSingletonScope();
```

Is this going to re-use the same HttpClient everywhere and not "newing" up a new one? :)

Comment: You might want to read [this answer about constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682042/usage-of-binding-to-constants-and-binding-to-types-in-scopes-with-ninject)

Comment: Yes that is fine

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking about whether it is the right thing to register `HttpClient` as singleton, then yes, it is.

Microsoft docs:

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout
>   the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for
>   every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy
>   loads. This will result in SocketException errors.

In case of how to register it as singleton with Ninject, there are two options which are basically the same:

```
Bind<HttpClient>().To<HttpClient>().InSingletonScope();

Bind<HttpClient>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

PS. If you are able to install [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) package(works for both .Net framework and .Net Core) it is better to use `HttpClientFactory`. It will manage your HttpClient instance in the most effective way(keeping `HttpClient` in memory is not the most efficient way in 100% cases). How to use it you can read [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore)

Comment: Is there any way to use the new HttpClientFactory with Ninject? I can only find examples of it for NET Core and not for full framework (net472).

Comment: @Vinod all the Nuget packages built on .NET Standard. So you can use them in Framework as well

Comment: So to answer @Vinod question, would you use `Bind<IHttpClientFactory>().To<IHttpClientFactory>().InSingletonScope();`?

Comment: @ChrisWalsh does it work? (Bind<IHttpClientFactory>().To<IHttpClientFactory>().InSingletonScope();)

Comment: @zolty13 no because I haven't bound `IHttpClientFactory` so the RHS remains unbound.